# What tools are available to free allocated space in a MySQL database after deleting data?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL Server-5.1.58 Community log. The problem is after deleting the data the allocated space of MySQL database is not getting free and as a result day by day the backup size of my using database is increasing.

Please kindly let me know any tool which can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that **MySQL locks the table during the time OPTIMIZE TABLE is running**

For your MySQL version from the official documentation:

> OPTIMIZE TABLE should be used if you have deleted a large part of a
>   table or if you have made many changes to a table with variable-length
>   rows (tables that have VARCHAR, VARBINARY, BLOB, or TEXT columns).
>   Deleted rows are maintained in a linked list and subsequent INSERT
>   operations reuse old row positions. You can use OPTIMIZE TABLE to
>   reclaim the unused space and to defragment the data file

Additional notes for InnoDB:

> For InnoDB tables, OPTIMIZE TABLE is mapped to ALTER TABLE, which
>   rebuilds the table to update index statistics and free unused space in
>   the clustered index. Beginning with MySQL 5.1.27, this is displayed in
>   the output of OPTIMIZE TABLE when you run it on an InnoDB table, as
>   shown here:
>
> mysql> OPTIMIZE TABLE foo;
>   Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead

So:

```
OPTIMIZE [NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG | LOCAL] TABLE
    tbl_name [, tbl_name] ...
```

> By default, OPTIMIZE TABLE statements are written to the binary log so
>   that they will be replicated to replication slaves. Logging can be
>   suppressed with the optional NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG keyword or its alias
>   LOCAL.